# Linux GeForce GTX driver is underreporting RAM and underperforming in general

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers, nvidia-geforce

I have just installed Kubuntu 12.04 on an Alienware M17x R4. It has Intel integrated graphics and a GeForce GTX 660M.

```
#> sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
#> sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia linux-headers-generic
```

Seemed to work.

```
#> lspci
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0fd4 (rev ff)
```

0fd4 is suspicious, other people's lspcis seem to give a name instead.

Nevertheless, I tried the Unigene Heaven demo with `optirun` and it works, but only at about 10fps, whereas older and lower-spec machines have much, much higher framerates. Here's some output:

```
Renderer: NVIDIA NV70 (Kepler) 256MB
OpenGL vendor:   NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer: GeForce GTX 660M/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL version:  3.2.0 NVIDIA 304.88
OpenGL flags:    Core Profile
```

It thinks there are **256MB** available. Booting into Windows, it is a **2GB** card.

So it's as if the driver thinks the card is lower-spec than what it really is. Which is strange, because the model number is right.

**So why the low performance?**

(I have desktop effects disabled. No luck running the benchmark on Windows yet, it wants to link to MSVCPP100.dll but I only have MSVCPP110.dll apparently.)

Comment: Not really sure I can help but a couple of quick and easy troubleshooting tips from https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Troubleshooting suggests a) nuke `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` (`sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf`) b) update kernel or c) update the drivers though it looks like your drivers are already up to date...

Comment: Ubuntu does not have an xorg.conf. I'm pretty sure everything is up-to-date, although I don't know how to find the driver build number.